# GeoServer CSS point attribute filter removing data but visible on layer

Tags: geoserver, point, cql-filter, css, geoserver-styling

I am trying to create a point layer with the constraints as follows:

1. *If* [current year] - [year of data point] <= 3 then use square symbol *otherwise* use circle symbol
2. Regardless of the year of the data point, display the count of the latest year on the label

An image representation of the layer is shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xq1Us.png

The data exists as follows where for a given point there are multiple entries based on the year. I have computed field *year_rank* by ranking the year field on descending order and the *year_diff* field by getting the difference between the current year and the *year* field in the data.

[image: Sample data]

I have created the CSS styling as follows:

```
[year_diff<= 3] {
  mark: symbol(square);
  mark-size: 30;
  z-index: 1000;
}

[year_diff> 3] {
  mark: symbol(circle);
  mark-size: 30;
  z-index: 900;
}

[year_rank = 1] {
  label: [count];
  label-padding: 1;
  font-family: Red Hat Display ;
  font-size: 14;
  font-style: bold; 
  font-weight: normal;
  font-fill:white ;
  halo-color: black;
  halo-radius: 1; 
  halo-opacity:0.8;
  label-fit-goodness: 0;
  label-geometry: [centroid(geom)]; 
  label-anchor: 0.5 3; 
}
```

This may not be the optimal way to write the attribute based filters since it's based on z-index to place the square pins are on top of and higher priority over the circle pins, but I have found that it does the job apart from one behaviour that is unexpected to me.

**On the layer the pin shapes and the labels appear as expected, however the data being sent on the layer is missing the entry where *year_rank* is equal to 1** (See screenshot). The behaviour I want is the entry where year_rank is 1 to be present in the data as well.

[image: Selected point]

This is likely due to a misunderstanding on my part of how the filters are applied on GeoServer CSS styling, but I'm struggling to understand what my mistake is and how to correct it. Is there an alternative and more optimal way to achieve the requirements listed?

EDIT:

I have found a way to achieve what I wanted using the following CSS styling using z-ordering. It doesn't feel like a clean

```
[year_diff <= 3] [year_rank = 1] {
  mark: symbol(square);
  mark-size: 30;
  label: [count];
  label-padding: 1;
  font-family: Red Hat Display ;
  font-size: 14;
  font-style: bold; 
  font-weight: normal;
  font-fill:white ;
  halo-color: black;
  halo-radius: 1; 
  halo-opacity:0.8;
  label-fit-goodness: 0;
  label-geometry: [centroid(geom)]; 
  label-anchor: 0.5 3; 
  z-index: 1000;
}

[year_diff > 3] [year_rank = 1] {
  mark: symbol(circle);
  mark-size: 30;
  label: [count];
  label-padding: 1;
  font-family: Red Hat Display ;
  font-size: 14;
  font-style: bold; 
  font-weight: normal;
  font-fill:white ;
  halo-color: black;
  halo-radius: 1; 
  halo-opacity:0.8;
  label-fit-goodness: 0;
  label-geometry: [centroid(geom)]; 
  label-anchor: 0.5 3; 
  z-index: 900;
}

[year_diff<= 3] {
  mark: symbol(square);
  mark-size: 30;
  z-index: 800;
}

[year_diff> 3] {
  mark: symbol(circle);
  mark-size: 30;
  z-index: 700;
}
```